# Получение текущей записи из контекста

Tags: c#, entity-framework

В wpf есть такое свойство как IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem, позволяющее отображать например в TextBox'e ту же запись, которая выбрана в DataGrid. Как программно получить этот указатель?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может костыль, но сделал так:

```
USER user = DataGrid.SelectedItem as USER;
```